# Shorting links with bitly is truncating my full URL

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, bit.ly

I'm using vb.net to my web and I'm trying to short my URL with Bitly.
So far so good. Now, when I use multiple parameters in a URL, it being truncated.

URL example: `https://www.google.com/search?ei=JZJuXICFOLXaxgPqyrXYDQ&q=github&oq=github&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i131i67j0i67j0l8.5770.6610..6785...0.0..1.193.560.5j1....3..0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i131.TSeJXtGZpvc`

URL result: `https://www.google.com/search?ei=JZJuXICFOLXaxgPqyrXYDQ`

As you can see, the URL always is truncated when it finds the first "&".

Do know what is happening?

This is an example of my code:

```
Option Infer On

Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim wc = New WebClient()
        Dim login = "mylogin"
        Dim apiKey = "R_aaaaaaaaaaaaa1a11a11a11a11a1a11a1"
        Dim longUrl = System.Uri.EscapeUriString("https://www.google.com/search?ei=JZJuXICFOLXaxgPqyrXYDQ&q=github&oq=github&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i131i67j0i67j0l8.5770.6610..6785...0.0..1.193.560.5j1....3..0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i131.TSeJXtGZpvc")
        Dim request = String.Format("http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login={0}&apiKey={1}&longUrl={2}&format=txt", login, apiKey, longUrl)
        Dim result = wc.DownloadString(request)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider what your `request` string actually looks like. I have inserted line breaks for readability, of course there aren't any in the real thing:

```
http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=mylogin
    &apiKey=R_aaaaaaaaaaaaa1a11a11a11a11a1a11a1
    &longUrl=https://www.google.com/search?ei=JZJuXICFOLXaxgPqyrXYDQ
    &q=github
    &oq=github
    &gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i131i67j0i67j0l8
        .5770.6610..6785...0.0..1.193.560.5j1....3..0....1..
        gws-wiz.......0i71j0i131.TSeJXtGZpvc
    &format=txt
```

Do you see the problem? How is bitly supposed to know that `&q=github` and so on are *part of* `longUrl`, and not extra parameters?

The fix is simple. [As the documentation says](https://dev.bitly.com/v4_documentation.html) under Best Practices | Encoding:

> ## URL Encoding
>
> All long URLs sent to the Bitly API must be URL encoded, even if these
>   links already contain escaped characters. For more information about
>   URL encoding, see [this Wikipedia
>   article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm a few newbie about this but, do you mean I must substitute "&" symbol with "%26"? It doesn't work.
Can you be more specific with a solution? Really thank you so much.

Comment: Now, I'm using System.Uri.EscapeUriString() but It still doesn't work. (OP edited)